# How to design architecture for a customer model in Nodejs and Angularjs app?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, database-design

I am new in this programming world. I am self-learner and trying to build an application using MEAN tech. I am designing the customer model and need some review of my work before getting started.

Let's say **XYZ company** can have

- a company/ customer
- an organization: a set of companies with different locations

eg. if **abc** company have 4 locations so 4 locations will be treated as companies.

I am thinking the company and the customer is almost similar except few different field.

I need help in:

- designing model/ db design?
- is it a right way to do it? if no, can you please show me a right way
- I am also trying to build a logic to save multiple emails and contact numbers with name and value pair for a customer/company

  - customer: home, work, personal, son, daughter etc
  - company: head, manager, accountant etc.

like:

```js
email : [{
    name : String,
    value: String,
    eid: String, // _id = name+value
 }]
 contact_number : [{
    name : String,
    value: String,
    eid: String, // _id = name+value
 }]
```

I am new and open to all the suggestions. Consider this, this app is a management company who is working with the individual customer as well as wholesale companies too.

Comment: Close vote: not a good question for SO. There are a TON of potential solutions to this. There are a lot of customer management systems (CRM) out there you can use as prototypes if you're trying to roll your own. Salesforce, SAP, Microsoft Dynamics, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your input. you are right. I post the question after researching thro google. Sir, I am not an expert in this rn but I will surely check the prototypes you mentioned. I am trying to build my portfolio and got confused with so many options. @BLSully

Comment: David Hay's Enterprise Model Patterns Part 4

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan Thank you for the comment. I will sure check it out.